# Magento Product Collection Select all Attributes

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to create a model that selects a specific product and all it's attributes.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

But sadly although I have done this hundreds of times before, we're having a Magento moment...

```
echo $products->getSelect()->__toString();
```

reveals that ->addAttributeToSelect is ignoring me.

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
```

Of course in typical Magento fashion there are no exceptions or errors of any kinds.

I am calling these methods in my own Adminhtml Grid block, caching is disabled (even though I know Magento still caches some model data when caching is disabled(i deleted var/cache).

I can't even do:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

I'm really starting to loose my patience with this platform, I've been using it for 4 months and it seems to waste more time than it saves. Any help would be a life saver!

Comment: this select ALL product, not a specific one. You should had a condition to select only your one. Or you can load it directly Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to dig more into Magento to understand how Magento ORM works (what's with the [EAV structure](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value) and how [collections](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) actually work).

In order to get all the product attributes this is correct:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

What you are missing is the fact that Magento will not give you all the related queries for a collection when you do:

```
echo $collection->getSelect()//note: you don't need __toString(), read about OOP in PHP5
```

When you run the code just to get the collection Magento will run only the following query:

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
```

When you start looping through the collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($collection as $p) {
    echo $p->getName()."\n";//you can use in here any getCustomAttribute method
}
```

Magento will run additional queries to get all the attributes and values:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.* FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = 10)

SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 10) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 74, 75, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('496', '507', '531', '97', '494', '509', '499', '492', '498', '104', '495', '497', '936', '500', '476', '506')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 10) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 74, 75, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('272', '510', '875', '877', '903', '501', '935', '952', '904', '102', '513', '110', '859', '862', '508', '863', '525', '502', '107', '860', '273', '274', '526', '861')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 10) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 74, 75, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('100', '960', '503', '943', '99', '567', '270', '101')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 10) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 74, 75, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('940', '571', '271', '562', '878', '106', '879', '906', '873', '703', '105', '103', '942', '941', '96', '836', '931', '874', '876', '905', '109', '880', '493', '881', '481', '570')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 10) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 74, 75, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('572', '573', '704', '705', '568', '569')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0)
```

To understand more about which queries are run in various contexts create a empty script, load just `Mage::app()` and play with collections and set $_logAllQueries to true in `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`. Additional info: [here](http://blog.nexcess.net/2011/04/15/logging-database-queries-in-magento/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! That makes more sense already. My problem is that I'm passing the collection to the `setCollection()` method of a `Mage_Admin_Block_Widget_Grid`. I gave up trying to pass a `sales/quote_item` collection to the grid, that's what I really need. I suppose I'll just have to read more Magento core files. It's all a lot of effort to get some records out of a database and rendered into a table. Thanks again though.