# Magento getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() with addAttributeToSelect('*') not returning description

Tags: php, magento

I have below code to get all products data from magento but it is not returning me the description field. I'm only getting short_description. Actually,its missing several fields in addition to description. Anyway here is the code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->joinField(
                    'qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
            )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->addPriceData()
            ->addStoreFilter($store_id)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    $collection->setOrder('sku', 'desc');
```

This creates the following query when I var_dump it:

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `at_qty`.`qty`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`allow_open_amount`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`email_template`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`giftcard_amounts`, `e`.`giftcard_type`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`gift_wrapping_available`, `e`.`gift_wrapping_price`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`is_redeemable`, `e`.`lifetime`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`open_amount_max`, `e`.`open_amount_min`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`use_config_email_template`, `e`.`use_config_is_redeemable`, `e`.`use_config_lifetime`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`brand`, `e`.`brand_value`, `e`.`new_in`, `e`.`new_in_value`, `e`.`amconf_simple_price`, `e`.`volume_weight`, `e`.`product_3rd_type`, `e`.`product_3rd_type_value`, `e`.`product_sub_type`, `e`.`product_sub_type_value`, `e`.`product_type`, `e`.`product_type_value`, `e`.`parent_sku`, `at_inventory_in_stock`.`is_in_stock` AS `inventory_in_stock` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_inventory_in_stock` ON (at_inventory_in_stock.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND ((at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1))
```

So there is only short_description but I have no idea why description is not there.

I know I can do

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())
```

But I don't want to query the DB lots of times. Is there way to work around this or get those fields when I do getCollection()?

Update: It seems my main issue is, I'm only getting required fields when I run the first code. In section where I get `$collection` I want to include additional fields in the description page of the product. What would be the code for that without doing load for each single product?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento doesn't load initially all attributes when using the model collection like this,

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

It's select the table

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
```

Magento using the orm tables. If we dig more in this,

```
foreach($collections as $collection) {
    echo $collection->getName();
}
```

Now you can see the additional quires will be running.

For more details please go **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297084/magento-product-collection-select-all-attributes)**

But you can get all product detail collection from flat table without querying multiple time to database . For that you need to enable the flat in `admin-> system->configuration ->catalog->catalog-> Front end->` 
Here you can see the options to enable flat catalog

```
Use Flat Catalog Category -> Enable
Use Flat Catalog Product  -> Enable
```

For more details about flat catalog please go **[here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9088/what-are-the-differences-between-eav-and-flat-catalogs)**.

So now you see the query now it will like,

`SELECT 1 AS` `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`allow_open_amount`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`email_template`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`giftcard_amounts`, `e`.`giftcard_type`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`gift_wrapping_available`, `e`.`gift_wrapping_price`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`is_redeemable`, `e`.`lifetime`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`open_amount_max`, `e`.`open_amount_min`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`use_config_email_template`, `e`.`use_config_is_redeemable`, `e`.`use_config_lifetime`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`necklace_length`, `e`.`necklace_length_value` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`

But remember some methods are not available in flat catalog  and also if it is disabled.

```
Function Name                   Flat Catalog Enabled    Flat Disabled
setLoadProductCount($flag)       No                      Yes
setProductStoreId($storeId)      No                      Yes
addParentPathFilter($parent)     Yes                     No
addStoreFilter()                 Yes                     No
addSortedField($sorted)          Yes                     No
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try setting product attribute for `description` field "`Used in Product Listing`" to "`YES`". That will solve your problem and avoid individual product model load.

But make sure after change this attribute you have to re index data.

Comment: I figured that my problem is slightly different. I updated the question with additional information. So, for this particular one they set `short_description` as required and `description` is not. I need to find a way to include them in my first query.